# List all Classes WITHOUT Javadocs

Tags: java, javadoc

Is there any simple way to analyze source code to list the number of classes that don't have any javadocs?

As part of a technical debt exercise I want to list all these files and share the list out among the team to have the original authors write them.

Note: We are using gradle as build system

UPDATE...
So empty javadocs get created by default but our devs havnt filled them in much. Id like to be able to see all classes that dont have any description in the doc at class level. I dont mind about methods too much.

Comment: Your problem seems a lot more complex than this, because how do you define "has javadoc" ? Is it enough to have comments on class level, or on method level as well. What if you have an autogenerated javadoc like **/ @author Alex /**. It is technically a javadoc but has nothing in it

Comment: Apparently there should be. We have such report on sonar cube, although if i recall it shows number of undocumented public methods.

Comment: Speaking about SonarQube, why not add it in your continuous integration stack ?

Comment: Thanks.. update to question above

Comment: Updated my answer, does it fills your needs?

Answer (score 5):

An easy way would be to use [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html).

Download the jar file and create a config XML file (javadoc_checks.xml) like this:

```
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="JavadocType"/>
        <module name="JavadocMethod"/>
        <module name="JavadocVariable"/>
        <module name="JavadocStyle"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

Now run the following command (assuming everything is in the same directory and `src`  contains your code):

```
java -jar checkstyle-6.9-all.jar -c javadoc_checks.xml src/
```

If, for example, you just want to check for missing javadocs for classes and interfaces, then you just need this in the config XML:

```
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="JavadocType"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

And the output would be something like:

```
C:\src\com\example\Test.java:137: Javadoc comment missing.
C:\src\com\example\Test1.java:3: Javadoc comment missing.
C:\src\com\example\Test2.java:12: Javadoc comment missing.
```

There are a lot of options, you can see them in:

http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html

http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html

Comment: The problem with this approach is that intellij is auto generating Jdocs for us in the form      /**
 * Created by bob on 18/08/2015.
 */   This shows up as a javadoc even though it is all but useless.  I need to find classes that have no MORE info that the "created by" line

Comment: You can configure Checkstyle to throw an error if the javadoc is "invalid". Check documentation at http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html. For example, you can activate the `NonEmptyAtclauseDescription` module (javadocs that don't have for example @param or @return will be rejected) or `SummaryJavadocCheck` with the forbidden text "Created by *" (javadocs that have that text will be rejected).